# What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?

Tags: apt, gnupg

I frequently cross this issue, and always have to google for an answer. Does anyone have a permanent fix for BADSIG errors from `apt-get`?

> W: GPG error:
>   http://download.virtualbox.org lucid
>   Release: The following signatures were
>   invalid: BADSIG 54422A4B98AB5139
>   Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive
>   signing key)

Comment: Are you using apt-cacher-ng?

Comment: It is important that you understand what are GPG signatures on APT used for, the GPG signature validates that the repository contains packages provided from a trusted source. It ensures both integrity and authenticity.
Every time you add a new repository from some provider you will need to add it's GPG key.

Comment: follow the example in the link - replace the example code in the linked answer with the BADSIG codes in your question.

Comment: fossfreedom, I couldn't get that solution to work on my system. Kept getting "--keyserver" was not understood. The solution offered by Dr.Ubuntu below worked for me.

Comment: Have a look also here http://askubuntu.com/questions/67594/unable-to-repair-packages-in-ubuntu-software-center/67603#67603 I think the commands you are using are correct, your just not using the correct key.

Comment: Yes, @portablejim, `apt-key list` lists `1024D/3E5C1192` key.

Comment: That is important information, but it doesn't answer the question at all. The asker may very well understand that already.

Comment: also your hash-sum mismatch error will be resolved by this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93114/error-with-ubuntu-update-manager-and-sotware-center

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Here's the (easiest) solution:

Type the following commands in the Terminal:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get clean
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mkdir -p lists/partial
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
```

[Credits: ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html)

**Edit:**

If the error occurs again (maybe after a few days/months), open Nautilus as root > navigate to `var/lib/apt` > delete the "lists.old" folder > then open the "lists" folder and delete the "partial" folder. Now, execute the aforementioned commands again.

Comment: This solves the more common error for me--updating through an Internet connection with a proxy (WiFi "cafe" that requires web logon) which corrupts some of my lists if I get logged off or forget to log on during an update.

Comment: What would the actual error be if qbi's answer doesn't help but this does?

Comment: It also happens to me because of: WiFi "cafe" that requires web logon

Comment: I wish the OP would check this as the answer!

Comment: @ArtOfCode: the error is exactly the same. This answer helped me, but on the web you only find the method that qbi points out and that you can find everywhere on the web.

Comment: Note that this is also documented solution on the VirtualBox linux [download pages](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), under "What to do when experiencing The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG ... "

Comment: meet exactly the same error and successfully solve with this solution, thanks

Answer (score 68):

The important part of your error message is the following in **bold**:

> W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG **54422A4B98AB5139** Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key)

Copy the stuff in **bold** and then open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 54422A4B98AB5139
```

i.e. paste using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>INS</kbd> the number you have copied - **54422A4B98AB5139**

You'll have to enter your password, the key will be downloaded and integrated.

Comment: my error was related to a bad repo, not just the key missing ... however your answer is likely valid for 99% of the cases

Comment: +1 because that's quite a useful thing to know how to do. However, it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Has this actually worked for anyone?

Comment: BADSIG is different than NO_PUBKEY.  For BADSIG the answer below solved it.  I'm not sure how I ended up in this situation, but I had BADSIG on 5 different PPAs even after importing the keys.

Comment: I believe this could be very dangerous in a situation where somebody is trying to do something nasty (man in the middle attack for example). **Don't just add keys from error messages. Only add keys you trust.**

Comment: How long should the keyserver take in responding to the request for the key? Let's say I'm on a public wifi.

Comment: The solution Srinivas Gollapudi provided should be considered a better solution.  If the above approach provides similar results, it doesn't necessarily mean its better or safer.  As gertvdijk mentioned the adding of keys could itself be a security risk.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: @Casey If it didn't solve your problem, you shouldn't accept the answer. You might want to accept a different answer instead.

Answer (score 31):

Try deleting the key

```
sudo apt-key del 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

then updating the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should get a `NO_PUBKEY` error instead of a `BADSIG` error and

```
sudo apt-key finger
```

should **not** find the key (called "Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key")

Now add the key

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

The result of `apt-key finger` should have

```
pub   1024D/3E5C1192 2010-09-20
      Key fingerprint = C474 15DF F48C 0964 5B78  6094 1612 6D3A 3E5C 1192
uid                  Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

---

If that does not work, try

```
apt-get clean            # Remove cached packages
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old       # Backup mirror info
mkdir -p lists/partial   # Recreate directory structure
apt-get clean
apt-get update           # Fetch mirror info
```

Source: [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10961816) ubuntu forums thread

Comment: I had multiple BADSIG errors which included even the standard Ubuntu archives. When I deleted VirtualBox key suddenly all those errors turned into NO_PUBKEY. Then when I added the VirtualBox key the errors disappeard for all the other repos. So it turned out that one bad key produced errors for many other unrelated repos.

Answer (score 12):

Another easier way to resolve BADSIG GPG errors is via a software called `Y PPA manager`

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager

Click on `Advanced`
[image]

And then select `Fix all GPG Badsig errors`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you still have this error after adding the key try:

1. goto your apt-cacher-ng cache directory, and delete the virtualbox entry:

   ```
   cd /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng
   sudo rm -rf download.virtualbox.org
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Found another server that we could use:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys [YOURKEYINQUESTION]
gpg --armor --export [YOURKEYINQUESTION] | sudo apt-key add -
```