# How to fix GPG error/BADSIG while running apt-get update?

Tags: upgrade, apt, update-manager, repository, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Of late, I've been getting this long list of errors every time I run apt-get update from the terminal. These errors weren't there before, I have no clue how they cropped up all of a sudden. I even tried some methods as suggested in some forums, but they apparently haven't worked for me so far. I've even tried changing the server, but to no avail. I'd be really glad to receive help on this issue.

The errors are here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/544093/

Answer (score 1):

Type the following in your terminal one by one,

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2E206FF0`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 17CF995E`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 298C1C9F`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E21DD54D`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5139BD61`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9E5DB0C8`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4631BBEA`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0624A220`

**Note:**

- After running all the above commands you may get few errors, because i have found lot of errors in your result,post the complete output of `sudo apt-get update` after running all those commands.So that i may help you.

Comment: You can also make this one command and separate the keys with blanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a transparent proxy between you and the Ubuntu archive? It seems that several of the Packages files are not being fetched correctly (which results in the GPG failures). Try this from the command line:

```
curl -I http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release
```

Does that show something like this? (The first line showing "200 OK" would be expected if things aren't totally broken.)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 23 Dec 2010 21:08:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:00:00 GMT
ETag: "f72018-dfca-4924b34083c00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 57290
Content-Type: text/plain
```

If this looks clean, try it again:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in terminal,

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-extras-keyring`

`sudo apt-get update`

**Note:**

- If you get any errors after running the above commands,post the output here.

Comment: I did as you told. This is what I got on apt-get update:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/546976/

Comment: @Pawan-Neupane Delete the old keys first and then import the key.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I delete old keys? All the keys or just those two?

Comment: @Pawan-Neupane Goto **Software sources>>Authentication tab** and then delete the following keys **40976EAF437D05B5**    **FC918B335044912E** **16126D3A3E5C1192**

Comment: I removed the three keys you mentioned. Then, executed the three commands you suggested earlier. That didn't help either. So I repeated the first command for all three keys again. Still to no avail. Here's what I still get: http://paste.ubuntu.com/546987/

Comment: Type these [commands](http://paste.ubuntu.com/546994/)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

Keep me informed

Comment: @Karthick87, is your question answered?