# Why does BADSIG/GPG error keep appearing again and again?

Tags: update-manager, repository, software-sources, gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix GPG error/BADSIG while running apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17606/how-to-fix-gpg-error-badsig-while-running-apt-get-update)

I'm most frustrated at not being able to get rid of the BADSIG/GPG errors I get while running apt-get update. This is what I get when running the command:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/546690/

I tried cleaning the cache, changing the server to Main Server, and even tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key>
```

None of that seems to solve my problem though.

Help on this would be highly appreciated.