# Reloading the package manager gives a GPG error

Tags: 11.10, apt, gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Reloading the package manager gives me an error:

```
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 73AD8184264CE9C6 Launchpad PPA for Simon Schneegans
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do about it?