# Unable to remove Pidgin software completely

Tags: 11.10, ppa, update-manager, software-sources, pidgin

I'm getting an error on the task bar each time I turn on my phone and used to ask me to check for updates. Here is the message on the task bar:

> The update information is updated.This maybe caused by a network error or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by clicking on this icon and then selecting 'check for updates' and check if some of the listed repository fail.

But when I do this it says no updates available.

I opened package manager and pressed the reload button and got this message box:

> W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key 
>   W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key
>
> W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key 
>   W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I saw the Pidgin repositories creating issues in this message ([Reloading the package manager gives a GPG error](https://askubuntu.com/q/64721/11019)) and removed the Pidgin PPA from my software sources, but each time I restart it it shows the two Pidgin PPA and the software as well. Can anyone tell me how to remove it completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Answer (score 4):

To remove Pidgin completely you have to remove the `pidgin-ppa` package (besides the pidgin package) by entering the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge pidgin-ppa
```

This package is responsible for setting up Pidgin PPA in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pidgin-ppa.list`.

To test that all Pidgin PPAs are removed type:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pidgin*
```

It should not list any files.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that W:GPG error by Simply Opening "Software Sources" and then removing the ppa link related to pidgin.