# Mate Desktop Environment won't uninstall from Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, package-management, uninstall, mate, environment

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and decided to install the Mate Desktop Environment to use it instead of Unity. I have installed Mate DE from the following repositories and apt sources:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa  
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
```

then the apt source

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras
```

I didn't like the results thought, too basic, so I decided to uninstall and keep using Unity until I feel like trying another desktop environment. So I used the following commands to uninstall Mate:

```
sudo apt-get purge mate-desktop-environment-core  
sudo apt-get purge mate-desktop-environment-extra  
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

My question is, why won't Mate uninstall? It keeps showing in the "Select desktop environment" list in the login screen of Ubuntu. Also, apps like MATE terminal and so on keeps showing in Ubuntu launcher. How to uninstall everything Mate related?

Comment: First question: Why do you think, Mate is still installed? And yes: You installed some other package you removed. Therefore, the dependencies might will still be there.

Comment: ...because the meta-packages do not pull down their dependencies. You must explicitly uninstall the mate-related packages you don't want.

Comment: According to [this website](http://sourcedigit.com/12228-uninstall-remove-mate-desktop-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) you need to run `sudo apt-get remove mate-*` to remove any packages that have `mate-` in them. ___DO NOT JUST RUN `sudo apt-get remove mate*` AS THIS CAN BREAK YOUR INSTALLATION___

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have finally solved it by following the instructions given in the link you posted. Thank you so much! PD: How to select best answer?

Comment: I have to post it first, which I will do.

Comment: You'll see a little check mark under the vote options on my actual answer. Click that to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove MATE Desktop, just run `sudo apt-get remove mate-*`. This will remove anything relating to the MATE desktop environment. ***Do not run `sudo apt-get remove mate*`, as this can break your installation.***

Source: http://sourcedigit.com/12228-uninstall-remove-mate-desktop-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: if running on zsh shell add '\ ' before `*`   run:  `sudo apt-get remove mate-\*`