# How to uninstall pidgin 2.11.0

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, pidgin, facebook

I compiled and installed Pidgin 2.11.0 according to the instruction given in [Linuxbabe.com](https://www.linuxbabe.com/instant-messenger/compile-install-pidgin-2-11-0-ubuntu-16-04)
but after that I could not connect Facebook to the pidgin. I used a plugin called "purple-facebook" to conncet Facebook with pidgin before but after the upgrade that plugin does not appear in pidgin accounts manager. I tried to uninstall it but that does not work.Simply  "sudo apt purge pidgin" does not work. Anybody have any idea to solve this matter. 
Regards

Comment: I followed the guideline given in (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64759/how-do-i-remove-uninstall-a-program-that-i-have-complied-from-source). I triggered the command ./configure and then make uninstall. But it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge pidgin-ppa
```

[Unable to remove Pidgin software completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75811/unable-to-remove-pidgin-software-completely)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is not going to help OP because OP didn't install pidgin using `pidgin-ppa`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I didn't install pidgin via a ppa. I compiled it from the source. So i think apt or apt-get commands will not work with this situation. Thank you again for your kind help.