# Unable to repair packages in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 11.10, package-management

When I open up the Software Center it gives me, "Items cannot be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired". Can someone help me?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update` from the terminal before installing applications from the Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal and use these commands

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the last one you should be able to open your `USC` again without faults.

**Edit**

Comments explain that key 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 is missing, during `sudo apt-get update` this fault comes up:

`W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0`

To repair the key these commands can be used:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
sudo gpg --export --armor 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 | sudo apt-key add -
```

After that `sudo apt-get update` should work, if you get no faults on it you can open `USC` again and click on the repair button.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gives me the same error in USC

Comment: Do you get any faults at all during `sudo apt-get update`? Do a `sudo apt-get clean` and try those steps again.

Comment: On sudo apt-get update I got: inline `W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0`,

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys` followed by `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0` will do it for you I think (you have to type the 2 commands not only the last).

Comment: I did that and i still get the same error in USC.

Comment: got any output there? (faults?)

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get update` again to check for the same fault plz and if that fault is still there do: `sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0` followed by a `sudo gpg --export --armor 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: I had no faults when running the command `sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0`, and `sudo gpg --export --armor 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 | sudo apt-key add -`,

Comment: then try just a `sudo apt-get update` again and check for faults.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get update` and got no faults at all.

Comment: `USC` should open. else force and upgrade with `
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: After I opened it it still gives me the same error. `Items cannot be install or removed until the package catalog is repaired` EDIT: Now when i clicked repair it fixes it. Thank you very much! =D

Comment: welcome, glad it worked. ill edit the answer to reflect all this info!

Comment: done, tick the "checked" box if you agree with the answer. regards