# can not install update and software

Tags: installation, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bypass/remove/disable the untrusted package authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71188/how-to-bypass-remove-disable-the-untrusted-package-authentication)

can not install update and software.
whenever i try to do so error comes with-

"Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

and the installation gets stop.