# Installation of software from Ubuntu software centre

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bypass/remove/disable the untrusted package authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71188/how-to-bypass-remove-disable-the-untrusted-package-authentication)

When i try to install softwares from software centre i get an error message as follows :

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
```

in details the following is mentioned:

> libcddb2 libdvbpsi7 libebml3 libiso9660-8 libmatroska5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsidplay2 libtar0 libupnp3 libva-x11-1 libvcdinfo0 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0

Whether I click on `OK` or `Repair` either ways the window closes and I cannot download & install the software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article. 
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/10/fix-requires-installation-untrusted-packages-error-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/

Even if they are talking about version 10.10 i believe the solution they provide will help you. The key is to use the underlined number and make sure you update your package repository.