# Can't install any software from software center

Tags: 12.04, software-center, package-management

When I am trying to install a software from software center it show me this:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
```

Comment: Did you change anything in the time since the last time it worked?

Comment: Where are you installing this from? Is it from a PPA?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/71188/62483

Comment: Also, possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/117015/62483

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified any software sources?  Did you download what you are trying to install from somewhere?  If so, it is saying that the application is not trusted.  You can choose to install it but you run the risk of an unstable system

Comment: I installed medibuntu and then fetching this problem