# Software Center Fails - CANT find the "duplicate" answer

Tags: software-center

I have the problem not being able to download software I keep getting the error to check internet connection then sometime something about an untrusted source.  I see this has been asked but keeps getting marked as a duplicate can someone please direct me to the ORIGINAL question, I have looked and looked and can't find the resolution.

THANKS SOO MUCH!

Comment: Is this your Problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/71188/how-to-bypass-remove-disable-the-untrusted-package-authentication

Comment: I found the fix!! I had to change the server location - although I wasn't able to utilize "shift + f2" but was able to get it changed regardless - thanks for the screenshot that helped me!  FYI here is the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/73997/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-download-package-files-error