# Errors running apt-get update after upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt, updates, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

I recently updated my Chromebook that was running Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and since updating, whenever I run `apt-get update` I get the following errors:

```
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

The repositories look like they're the primary repositories for 11.10, so I am assuming that this is a pretty bad error.  The rest of the update happens without any problems, it is just these three repos that error.  Is there something that I can do about the bad signatures?

Answer (score 3):

Found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

> Here's the (easiest) solution:
>
> Type the following commands in the Terminal:
>
> ```
> $ sudo -i
> # apt-get clean
> # cd /var/lib/apt
> # mv lists lists.old
> # mkdir -p lists/partial
> # apt-get clean
> # apt-get update
> ```
>
> Credits: ubuntugeek.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a script that allowes you to obtain any missing GPG keys for your repositories.
run the following commands in the terminal, one at a time:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
```

and then run  `sudo launchpad-getkeys`

it will port to you all missing signatures.
after that you will see no errors when updating the repos.

please see this post, and read it before. source : http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html

Comment: I tried that but it didn't get the keys to fix my errors.  I posted the solution that worked for me.