# Cannot update system - Error during signature verification

Tags: upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Okay, usually I run an apt-get update and upgrade about once a day. Now suddenly it's telling me this:

```
Fetched 666 B in 6s (105 B/s)                                                  
W: GPG error: ttp://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: ttp://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: Failed to fetch ttp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release  

W: Failed to fetch ttp://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now, in all my time of using Ubuntu I have never seen this, so I am quite confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thankyou,

Ross

( I have taken out the leading (h) in http on purpose, due to link posting restrictions. )

Answer (score 12):

It seems to be a bug. There is solution described which rebuilds the cache, see 
"[Invalid signature for extras.ubuntu.com](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-extras-keyring/+bug/893743/comments/7)" and this worked for me.

Comment: This just fixed it for me too

Comment: Helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It has just started this morning happening again (2/12/11:12:00 GMT). I presume that something messed up the automatic signing process and it will be back when the next update is pushed through.

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently with es.archive.ubuntu.com and I agree with Stuart on that this is a temporary failure.

In the meantime, I suggest the following workaround:

- Launch `Software Sources`
- Select `Main Server` from the `Download from` dropdown list

That will change your sources from gb.archive.ubuntu.com to just archive.ubuntu.com wich should work fine. Alternatively, you can look at `Other...` and select another server in the UK.