# GPG error from apt-get

Tags: 11.10, apt, aptitude, gnupg, signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Whenever I run apt-get update or apt-get install I get an error akin to the following:

```
W: GPG error: http://au.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://au.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am skeptical about just removing the keys without replacement keys; so thought it best to ask here.

**How do I replace the signatures; and what should I replace them with?**

Comment: This was already discussed here. See http://askubuntu.com/q/1877/37765 for the question and http://askubuntu.com/a/64544/37765 for a fix.

Comment: So I shouldn't use the fix accepted by the askee?