# update manager fails to update - badsig errors displayed in synaptic

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Update manager claiming that i did't check for updates but i do?

the system is telling me that i did not check for update (last time 20 days ago) but i did a minute ago.. I'm using gnome shell (installed KDE and gnome)
here the synaptic output

```
W: GPG error: http://sd.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Use another mirror.

Answer (score 4):

Try these commands...

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

This will rebuild the cache !