# The following signatures were invalid

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

I use ubuntu 11.10 latest update, but when I change the ubuntu update server to the main server i get this error:

```
sudo apt-get update
......
......

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 198 B in 16s (11 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

i tried many solutions from google but nothing helps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Some ISPs cache the packages and errors like these are reported then. If the above commands don't work, try

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True
```

and again

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it still doesn't work,

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true 

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If all set, u can make it permanent, so that no problem in future persists by editing

**/etc/apt/apt.conf**

```
APT 
{
// Options for the downloading routines
  Acquire
  {
    http
    {
      No-Cache "true";
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried all these solution and still have the error message. My problem was, that my Virtual Ubuntu freeze while I'm installing sublime. And now apt is broken and always see this error. Any help? thanks.