# Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050: Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg

Tags: apt, software-center, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed, since about 1 month ago i can't install any program from software center, or synaptic or terminal, and also i can not update my installed software. Here is a screenshot from Software center:

[image]

You see there is neither info of the program nor the install bottom. (in "Software Source", multiverse source is checked)

The log of command `sudo apt-get upgrade` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and the log of command `sudo apt-get update` is:

```
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
Err https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages
  couldn't connect to host
Err https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  couldn't connect to host
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/debfx/virtualbox/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/flareget-amd64/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/debfx/virtualbox/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/flareget-amd64/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:

W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/motorbike/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  couldn't connect to host

W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/motorbike/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  couldn't connect to host

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

In update manager when i want to check for updates it says:

Unable to download the following packages:

```
Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/InRelease Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/InRelease Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/InRelease Failed to download http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050: Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050: Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050: Failed to download http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050: Failed to download http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050:
```

Please help.

P.S. I already have seen this [Update Manager unable to get updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91193/update-manager-unable-to-get-updates), but that didn't help me, so please don't mark this question as a duplicate

Comment: what is `127.0.0.1:9050` ?? How any request is redirecting to your own interface! check `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: i used that whenever working with tor to set proxy, but know i don't use that and the proxy is set to none. but the etc/hosts file is as follow: 
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 HPCU
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to connect" error with apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164169/unable-to-connect-error-with-apt-get)

Comment: No reproducible per [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8973954#8973954) "hi mohammad, i don't know what happend just now, i didn't changed anything since last try but it's working know, thanks to you any way"

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you've set a proxy server "127.0.0.1:9050"; maybe some anti-filtering programs or something like that. so if you don't persist on using this proxy, open **network** and set proxy to none (or any other proxies you need) and click on set system wide. then you should have the ability to use `sudo apt-get update` to update the list of packages and then install them via `sudo apt-get install` or using synaptic or software-center.

If you persist on using proxy server, first check if you can access internet with that proxy (using firefox or any other browser with that proxy and opening a website). then set the proxy in **network** and set system wide. remember that if your proxy needs authentication, you must edit the **/etc/apt/apt.conf** file by hand to something similar to

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port";

Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxy:port";

Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@proxy:port";
```

Comment: as i said in comment above, proxy is set to none, i don't know why is that happening

Comment: check "/etc/apt/apt.conf" "~/.profile" and "~/.bashrc" and look for proxy settings and delete the lines. if there was anything in profile, you may should logout and relogin to have new environment

Comment: "/etc/apt/apt.config" is an empty file

Comment: did you check .profile and .bashrc ,too?

Comment: try echo $http_proxy in terminal and it must return nothing if bashrc and profile doesn't contain anything related to proxy.

Comment: echo $http_proxy returnd "http ://127.0.0.1:9050/" , but i can't find "~/.bashrc" and "~/.profile" that you mentioned. do they must be in "/etc/apt/" folder?

Comment: ~ means $HOME which is your home directory "/home/user/" and there should be .profile and .bashrc files. remember that they are hidden and you should press ctrl+H to unhide them

Comment: ok i found them, and they don't have anything about proxy

Comment: it must be somewhere within ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile . but if you cannot find them you may use "export http_proxy=" and similar for https and ftp. it should work temporarily

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8329/discussion-between-mehdi-and-mohammadh-montazeri)