# Cant install software

Tags: software-center

So I just installed the ubuntu 11.10 ..

And when i goto software center and try to download any software(use source)..

all i get is a window saying that "Failed to download repository information" , "check your internet connection" and

```
W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch htt p ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch http ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch htt ://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_restricted_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch ht tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch h tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch h ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_multiverse_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch ht  tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_restricted_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch htt  p://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
, W:Failed to fetch h ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_main_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch h ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_multiverse_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch ht tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_restricted_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch  ht tp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_universe_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

Neglect the http typos, its to evade the 2 hyperlink..

I tried making a file in the apt.conf.d folder also, and added proxy entries, also set the system proxy.. and also the "network proxy",  but nothing works..

And now I cant install any software!!  Help needed

Comment: is this a fresh,clean installation or did you just upgrade from any other version of Ubuntu?  are you using 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Comment: Try changing the software source to some other mirror, may be it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your internet connection, make sure that it is indeed working. I noticed that you mentioned this was a fresh installation.

Take a look here

[Error with Update Manager and Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93114/error-with-ubuntu-update-manager-and-sotware-center)

Comment: I dont think thats the problem..  coz I checked the internet part.. What about "A hash mismatch is usually a sign of a broken mirror"