# Problems while doing 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, gnome-tweak-tool

I started facing this sudden issue a few days ago when I was once trying to 'update' and 'upgrade', something regarding corruption of package index files in the apt-repository and I've not been able to figure this out; here, following is the output on the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for adarshc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-generic-lts-raring
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apt apt-transport-https apt-utils avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils base-files bc bind9-host chromium-browser
  chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg consolekit dc dnsutils duplicity firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer fonts-opensymbol gdm
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-tweak-tool gnupg gpgv grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common iproute landscape-client-ui-install language-pack-en
  language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base libaccountsservice0 libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
  libbind9-80 libcec2 libck-connector0 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libdns81 libdrm-intel1
  libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libgail-3-0 libglu1-mesa libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgtk-3-0
  libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjpeg-turbo8 liblwres80 libnfs1 libnss3 libnss3-1d libpam-ck-connector
  libpixman-1-0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-human
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer libsmbclient libssl1.0.0 libunity-2d-private0 libunity-core-5.0-5 libwbclient0 libxfixes3 libxfont1
  libxi6 linux-firmware linux-generic-lts-raring linux-libc-dev openssl pm-utils python-appindicator python-software-properties python-uno qdbus rar
  rsyslog samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk thunderbird
  thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support ubuntu-tweak unity unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread
  unity-common unity-services uno-libs3 ure xbmc-bin xbmc-pvr-argustv xbmc-pvr-dvbviewer xbmc-pvr-mediaportal-tvserver xbmc-pvr-mythtv-cmyth
  xbmc-pvr-nextpvr xbmc-pvr-njoy xbmc-pvr-tvheadend-hts xbmc-pvr-vdr-vnsi xbmc-pvr-vuplus
159 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
E: The package index files are corrupted. No Filename: field for package gnome-tweak-tool.
```

Comment: for the error in the last line, see this question, it had the same issue, the first answer should help you remove the corrupted index files.....http://askubuntu.com/q/93114/65969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here are the steps that should fix your problem.

This will clean out downloaded archives

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will check for the latest packages and updates available

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will push apt to update all available packages

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the above, but sorry, it doesn't work and gives the same error message: "E: The package index files are corrupted. No Filename: field for package gnome-tweak-tool."

Comment: @user237254 Does are these command lines good to be used just for maintenance, not only to fix something (like in Adarsh's case)? I mean, to use them to prevent, not to treat, sort to speak...

Comment: @AdarshChauhan, did you change something in your /etc/apt/sources.list file?  That can throw errors as well.  Usually when I see a response about a corrupt package I just run apt-get clean and it cures it.  Only other one that I use is apt-get autoclean but I believe autoclean is for removing old unused packages while clean dumps all your current apt cache.  Try and verify you can access the package with this: sudo apt-cache search gnome-tweak-tool     If you can, then try doing a: sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool   If that works and you still can't get upgrade to work.......  hmm.....

Comment: @CristianaNicolae, I use these in my toolbox for both maintenance and troubleshooting.  It has saved me countless hours of beating my head against the wall when I couldn't figure out why some packages were being held back, or when I would get a corrupt package, etc.  I usually apt-get update a few times a week and dist-upgrade or upgrade as necessary.  Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you, @SierraJuliet for the follow up. But, unfortunately, it is still not working it seems. It seems that there is no package index file named 'gnome-tweak-tool' in the apt-repository list and cleaning it, and building it up again gives the following as the last line in the terminal:
"E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
I would appreciate if any of your past relevant experience can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do this first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Pardon, I forgot to mention that I already tried upgrading after doing the 'sudo apt-get update'.