# Getting error while trying to do software update

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop. When I tried to install a package using terminal I got some errors like it has no installation candidate.For different package also I got the same error.Then I tried to do software update of my ubuntu.But when I tried I got the error like - 
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
Since I am well connected to a LAN connection ,so I don't think its my network problem,but I don't know where the problem is.Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Here is a solution of your problem. Try this [Link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93114/error-with-update-manager-and-software-center).

Answer (score 0):

It's a network problem. Just because you are connected to LAN doesn't guarantee (full) Internet access. If you know you have Internet access then it may be a firewall issue.

Try to ping the repository and see if you get a DNS resolution and response. For example, if you are using the U.S. repository then try this:

```
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

If you are in another country then you should use a repository closer to you. You can check your sources (/etc/apt/sources.list) to see which servers you are trying to connect to.

If you don't resolve or cannot ping then I suspect that you are being blocked.