# BADSIG error while updating

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

I have had too much troubled with this error. I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 11.10 and then it smoothly ran for 2 days. But, when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error message:

> W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The
>   following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu
>   Archive Automatic Signing Key

I have tried this method but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
sudo -i    
# apt-get clean
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mkdir -p lists/partial
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
```

What did I do I have tried all the methods but it again comes. What is the reason for this? Please help me!