# No gpg key from behind a firewall

Tags: ppa, gnupg, add-apt-repository, keyserver

Just stumbled over this closed thread here:
[GPG Error while running apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95979/gpg-error-while-running-apt-get)

Same problem here, Ubuntu 12.04 behind a firewall and proxy.

I dont think that matter is duplicate of the given topic.
So i reopen this matter in this thread.

My output:

```
root@musik-Aspire-7741:~# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58B98E87
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-  keyring /tmp/tmp.tWVMhyIMYh --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring     /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver     hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58B98E87
gpg: Key 58B98E87 of hkp Server keyserver.ubuntu.com request
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: No valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Conclusion: gpg is not working with `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80` via http.

Comment: If you have to go through a proxy, you need to tell GPG to use the proxy. Do you have `http_proxy` set? (`echo $http_proxy`)

Answer (score 10):

Behind proxy, environment variable `http_proxy` should be set. This can be done in either of the two ways.
1.Create `apt.conf` file in /etc/apt directory if not present and add the following line to it.
`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@server:port";`
2.Simply set the environment variable using the following command from terminal.
`export http_proxy=http://user:password@server:port`
Finally a small tweak, add -E option to the command for the environment variables to be used as follows
`sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 58B98E87`

Comment: the -E did the trick

Answer (score 3):

If you're behind a proxy, then you must set the `http_proxy` enviroment variable in Bash. The best way to do it is to open the root shell with `sudo bash`.

After this:

```
export http_proxy="http://xxx.yyy.zzz.www:abcd"
```

Then add the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent almost two days for this to install the latest version of MongoDB. But I was facing the same issue as shown below:

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.pvb8fwe4Rs --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//nsa-keyring.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

At last I installed mongoDB with the help of steps shared by "ellore".

1. Added http and https proxy in `apt.conf` file.
2. Added the env variables using `export http` and `https` command.
3. Added "-E" in the command line:

   ```
    sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
   ```

Then I got the below response:

```
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7F0CEB10: "Richard Kreuter <richard@10gen.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

And I have successfully installed MongoDB 3.0.7 as shown below,

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
```