# Confusion installing mongodb manually because of sitting behind a proxy

Tags: 12.04, installation, mongodb

I am forced to install `mongodb` manually on an Ubuntu server because the machine sits behind a proxy and there is no way to temporary open port 11371 for key exchange to happen.
I am following this official [mongoDB tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/).

So I downloaded the tgz and extracted it in `/usr/local/bin/mongodb`. Where I got confused is when assigning the ownership of the `/data/db` to the user `mongo`.

- So who creates the user `mongo`?
- How to get `control-scripts` working?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but I suggest you look further into how to install from packages instead. This question covers how to add a GPG key when behind a firewall/proxy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147311/no-gpg-key-from-behind-a-firewall

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the official package, it is much easier to get started.

Make sure you correctly set your `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in the terminal session and do whatever mentioned in the tutorial again.

I am also behind firewall (need proxy to access the Internet), everything works fine.

Example:

`export http_proxy="http://username:password@company.com:port/"`
`export https_proxy="http://username:password@company.com:port/"`

And also you can use apt-get install to install MongoDB

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/