# issues in installation of mongo DB

Tags: 12.04, apt, proxy, firewall, mongodb

I was installing mongo DB on my Ubuntu-12.04 system, but while i give the following command in my terminal

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

It gives me the following error

```
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Is there any other way of installing mongo db or what can be done to avoid the above situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command that is failing is the one that installs the key that is used to sign the MongoDB packages, so that `apt-get` can determine whether the packages are genuine.

You could try skipping installation of the key and adding `--allow-unauthenticated` when you run `apt-get` to install the packages. See [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt) for more detail.

But ideally, you need to figure out why you cannot connect to the key server to install the key.

Firstly, you can check your Internet connection and DNS by visiting http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ in a browser. If your Internet connection is working you will see a simple page entitled *SKS OpenPGP Public Key Server*. This shows that your computer can look up and connect to the key server.

If this is the case, then it is likely that the problem is a firewall or proxy server restricting your access to the specific port that `apt-key` wants to connect to. See [No gpg key from behind a firewall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147311/no-gpg-key-from-behind-a-firewall) for details for how to allow `apt-key` to connect via a proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with proxy, blocking connection to keyserver,  add http-proxy details in the apt-key command itself.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port --recv-keys KEYID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

otherwise use this package to install instead

http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/mongodb-10gen_2.2.2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

I have also mongodb installed in my system and I take the help from this site http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

And it always works.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Mongo Setup on AWS Ubuntu 14.0**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Add the lines below in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20121212"
extension=mongo.so
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Create a php file in `/var/www/html`, with these contents:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Run the file in a browser and find the Extension "Mongo".