# gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, apt, server, proxy, gnupg

I'm trying to install mongoDB on my Ubuntu 14

The first step was this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

But it showed me below error

```
    Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.lAXAyfkEwA --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linuxuprising-java.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openjdk-r-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-java.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: server: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I googled, got to know that's destination is somewhere where my machine is not able to make succesful request. Need to use proxy.

Came to this post

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/147311/no-gpg-key-from-behind-a-firewall
```

It says add `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@server:port";` in apt.conf file and try, but not success.

Doubt:

1) What's a actual purpose of using GPG keys in using an Database (mongoDb) ?

2) Do I need to add (`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@server:port`) as it is or I need to mention my username, server and password in apt.conf file ? If yes, How can I check my server name and port which I need to mention in file ? And username and password is my system's username and password I guess..Right .. ?

Thanks

Update: ping `-c 1 keyserver.ubuntu.com` return below

PING keyserver.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from boquila.canonical.com (91.189.89.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=144 ms

--- keyserver.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 144.294/144.294/144.294/0.000 ms

Comment: What kind of network are you on? Furthermore, please provide the **full** output of the command, not just the error message. Unless you are on a corporate network, you **probably** do not need a proxy server.

Comment: @vidarlo, Error updated and its my personal machine

Comment: What does `ping -c 1 keyserver.ubuntu.com` return? The proxy is most likely a blind track for you, if you're not on a corporate network.

Comment: @vidarlo, Updated in Question

Comment: Have you tried the command more than once? It works from here, name resolution works on your end, and there's no inherent reason that it should not work. Note: remove any proxy related settings before you try again...

Comment: @vidarlo..unsetting proxy Worked..! Thanks Man..! But could you please share why GPG keys are required to use mongoDB .. ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What's a actual purpose of using GPG keys in using an Database (mongoDb) ?

They're not used for the database. They are used to verify that the download. Apt uses gpg to sign package metadata, such as size and hashes, to ensure that a malicious mirror cannot feed you malicious packages.