# Ubuntu software center says "Ubuntu Software Center is not communicating"

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

when I open the ubuntu software center,

it shows nothing and when I close the tab appears a message "Ubuntu software center is not communicating"

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: dosnt resolve issue when i go to the synaptic package downloader and press reload this comes up and issue with the repositions packages

Comment: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG B725097B3ACC3965 Launchpad lfflGPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key

Comment: <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>GPG error: http://pr.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: thats the message that appears

Comment: @CARLOS Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/98217/edit) your post instead pasting in comments.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!