# Software center and update manager not working

Tags: update-manager, software-center

When I run update manager I always get this message "The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources." details "libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0"

I also can not get the software center to install anything. I get an error message telling me to check my internet connection but I am connected to the internet, shortly after I get an error message just like the one I get from update manager. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you get E: or W: errors with the result? If so could you post them here please

Comment: This can probably be fixed by http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877. Same symptoms

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to allow for installing untrusted 3rd party software.

From a command line, run `sudo apt-get update`

At the end of the command output, you will see an error similar to the following message:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6AF0E1940624A220
```

Copy the alpha-numeric string following the `NO_PUBKEY` message. In this case, it will be `6AF0E1940624A220`

Next, enter the following command, using the alpha-numeric string copied from the above-mentioned error message:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220`

This will load the applications public key into your list of 'trusted' sources.

After running this command, you should be able to install updates from the software center.

Answer (score 0):

You could open your software sources and in the box marked "source code" put a check there.

http://dailytechnoapps.blogspot.com/2011/12/fix-installation-of-packages-from-not.html

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the message, you can try to update and upgrade from the command line. It does not raise the same issues.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This shall do the trick.