# GPG Invalid Signature

Tags: gnupg, signature

I am having problems with the following (in an attempt to remove hyperlinks, I have removed one of the "/" from the addresses):

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were   invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG B725097B3ACC3965 Launchpad lffl

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 4874D3686E80C6B7 Launchpad PPA for Banshee Team

W: GPG error: http://archive.getdeb.net jaunty-getdeb Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A8A515F046D7E7CF GetDeb Archive Automatic Signing Key <archive@getdeb.net>

W: GPG error: http://badgerports.org lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG C90F9CB90E1FAD0C Jo Shields <directhex@apebox.org>

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 976B5901365C5CA1 Launchpad PPA for transmissionbt

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dlecan/openjdk/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dlecan/openjdk/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I have tried the following solutions which were in a closed case titled "The following signatures were invalid":

```
First of all try

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Some ISPs cache the packages and errors like these are reported then. 
If the above commands don't work, try

sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True

and again

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

If it still doesn't work,

sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true 

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: check this [post][1] in askubuntu .It worked for me


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116050/update-problems-due-to-installation-of-packages-from-not-authenticated-sources

Answer (score 20):

Try this one :

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my machine. :-(

Answer (score 4):

You have an "interesting" set of PPAs installed:

The one's reporting *BADSIG* can be solved by following this Q&A:

[What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

The 404 errors basically mean those PPA's no longer have oneiric repositories.  You should untick those from Software Sources.

The *jaunty-getdeb* & *badgerports.org*  repositories are not valid for oneiric.  Again, untick those from Software Sources.

Answer (score 0):

I got "Y PPA Manager". There is an "advanced" button in this software that will find your missing keys. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. I just unchecked the "independent-provided by third-party software developers" and "independent(source code)-provided by third-party software developers" check boxes under software sources (click on the gear icon on the main panel then click on software updater. on the bottom left is the settings button which will lead you to the software sources dialogue. when you get here, just move to the 'other software' tab)