# Update problems due to "installation of packages from not authenticated sources" error

Tags: 11.10

I have some problems updating my Ubuntu

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

cinnamon gir1.2-muffin-3.0 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libmuffin0 muffin-common
```

The downloads are from the Main server, the Source code under Ubuntu Software tab is marked

Is there something I have missed?

**The output of sudo apt-get update is:**

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A9653F936FD5529
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A777609328949509
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `sudo apt-get update` from a terminal is likely to reveal more information about which is coming from the untrusted source. This generally just means that you don't have the key for that repo yet.

If you are sure that the PPA is one you are happy to use then you can add the key with a terminal

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 36FD5529 28949509
gpg --export --armor 36FD5529 28949509 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope that helps

If you want to add PPA's in future you can use the add-apt-repository command, this will get the keys as well for you.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name

As far as the duplicate is concerned I would check your sources - you can open the file for editing as root and check for duplicates.

Backup the file first

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources/list.bak
```

Then

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Check for exact duplicates and put an # at the beginning of the line, save, exit and apt-get update.

Comment: I have updated the post :) with the output