# Problem in installing Build-essential on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

I want to install the `build-essential` package. I have tried with:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

But I get an error of package not found. I think this error is probably due to firewalled network of my company.

So I tried to download its debian package. When I run it, it gives me a dependency error on `g++4.6`.

So I try to install `g++4.6`, but it depends on `libstdc++6-4.6`. Then I try to install this library, but this one has a dependency on `g++4.6`.

So now I am confused to how to do this. Please help me.!!!

Comment: in your text you have:  sudo apt-get builds-essential --> it is not build[s] -essential, you have an extra char. [s]
the full command should be sudo apt-get install build-essential, the word [install]

Comment: yes, i made a mistake in writing it here, the correct command that i used was sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: where to post.??, it doesn't allow me to post here, coz of my reputation..

Comment: post the output in pastebin.com and then provide the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,it will install `build-essential` package,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If you face any dependency error then run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I have tried it, but it says "package not found".

Comment: Did you enable universe repository from software and updates?

Comment: I added a few lines, that i found on this site regarding universe in /etc/apt/sources.list, but it didn't help me.

Comment: If no then enable it and update the repositories by running sudo apt-get update.And then try to. run the command in my answer.

Comment: Search for software and updates in dash.After opening it,enable the universe repository.

Comment: I added following lines in /et/apt/sources.list 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security universe
and when i do sudo apt-get update, i get this error E: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

Comment: why you add quantal repository in precise?Please do what i said.

Comment: Please tell me what changes should i do..?

Comment: Search for software and updates in dash.After opening it,enable the universe repository.update the repositories by running `sudo apt-get update`.And then try to run the command given in my answer.

Comment: i still get error of GPG: invalid signatures: NODATA1 NODATA2

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get update` command on your question.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/104213/gpg-invalid-signature