# unable to update,It show the following errors.I am using ubuntu 11.10 32 bit in Lenovo Y450

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key 
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running this from the terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```