# Upgrade to 12.04 Failed due to held back packages

Tags: upgrade

I run upgrade after installing all recommended updates from update manager, and I got dialog:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug update-manager' in a terminal.
```

So I reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/989014).

I also tried

```
umpirsky@umpirsky:~$ sudo apt-get update
...
Fetched 16.6 kB in 1min 22s (200 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <email address hidden>
```

Any workaround for this?

- [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)
- First and second solution didn't work, last one returned `cd: /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng: No such file or directory`. Still getting GPG error.

Comment: On my part, the second solution does not work at all. It may work for others.

Comment: First and second solution didn't work, last one returned ` cd: /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng: No such file or directory`. Still getting GPG error. Thanks.

Comment: Please try a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and add the results into your question, it looks like you have some broken packages that might be throwing the upgrader off

Comment: @JorgeCastro ```sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for umpirsky: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too on my Lenovo Thinkpad due to ppa graphics dirvers. I solved it by installing ppa-purge and then removing the https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers ppa:

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

Comment: I worked..I just upgraded again all the packages for 12.04 and then I launched the upgrader to 12.10..and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and found that it was resolved by setting my software-sources back to the ubuntu.com site. (I had a faster mirror selected initially.)  Through software Center, I used the `Edit` menu --> `Software Sources ...` and on the dialog for Software Sources, I chose 'Main Server'.  I then ran `sudo apt-get update`.   After that, it could calculate the changes and upgrade.  This primary site was slower, but this solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Didn't work for me.