# I'm a beginner using Ubundu 12.04, I'm getting this error message whenever I try to update manually. Hope somebody will help. Thanks

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Reading package lists... Done
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. [The answer you need is here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors). Since this is a duplicate question I'm going to flag it for closure. Try the linked solution and post a new question if you still have problems. Good luck.