# apt-get works with --force-yes but cannot reproduce the issue on a fresh box

Tags: installation, server, apt

`apt-get` does not work the first time but works the second time.

I installed `ntp` like:

```
apt-get -q -y install ntp=1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1
```

It failed saying:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libcap2 libopts25 ntp
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Afterwards I ran:

```
apt-key update
```

and ran the same commad with `--force-yes`:

```
apt-get -q -y --force-yes install ntp=1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1
```

Thereafter running `apt-get purge` and reinstalling, `ntp` runs.

```
apt-get purge libcap2 libopts25 ntp  
apt-get -q -y install ntp=1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1
```

Also I created a fresh VM and could not reproduce the issue. On a fresh VM, the same `apt-get` command runs the first time, without `--force-yes`.

Two questions, why does running `apt-get` work the second time and cannot reproduce the error?

Full errors and sequential steps at https://gist.github.com/3017966.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your server (or use `sudo` for desktops):

```
apt-key net-update
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05B5
apt-get update
apt-get install ntp=1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1
```

The two apt-key commands will refresh the key. If you want to iterate over all your apt-key keys:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --verbose --refresh-keys
```

You should always `apt-get update` before you `apt-get install some-package`.

I think the basic problem is that you **haven't used apt-get update for a while**, the key got old probably and had to be checked/refreshed (I'm not 100% sure though).

Comment: @mediageek can i run `apt-key adv --recv-key` rather than `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 437D05B5`. Also how did you find the key 437D05B5 ?

Comment: @mediageek another problem is that, i am no longer able to reproduce the issue, even on a new vm. can i update the apt database to an older version and reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I think the basic problem is that you **haven't used apt-get update for a while**, the key got old probably and had to be checked/refreshed (I'm not 100% sure though). The key 437D05B5 is from the ubuntu keyserver, I compared from my own `sudo apt-key list`. I'll fix the command, you're right, use --recv-key. If you can't reproduce the problem, then it's solved. :)

Comment: @mediageek i will have to iterate over the keys in `apt-key list`. Is there a simpler way to update all keys ? Also, what is the difference between net-update and adv --recv-key ?

Comment: I have no idea frankly, but if one command fails, the other one works. Manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-key.8.html If you want to **iterate over all your apt-key keys** use: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --verbose --refresh-keys`