# Ubuntu can't update some repositories

Tags: repository, authentication, troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

[image]

Why can't Ubuntu update some repositories? especially from extras.ubuntu.com, PPA Tualatrix for Ubuntu Tweak, and Docky PPA.

In below, shows all my authentic keys, is any wrong?

[image]

sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

It appears that something must have broken your keys.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 6AF0E1940624A220
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 608BF7B93528AE20
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3BDAAC08614C4B38
sudo apt-get update
```

- [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Comment: thank you.. just it? is there anything to do? like remove old authenthic key?

could i know? which repository are keys for?

Comment: That should just redownload the keys needed. Hopefully you shouldn't have to do anything else, although there are other solutions in the link that Jorge added to my answer. The keys match up to the repos from the error. i.e. where it says "BADSIG 6AF0E1940624A220" you use that for the key to download.

Comment: still have same problem sir

Comment: Did you look at the link? It provides other solutions to your problem.

Comment: thank you.. so i won't accept it and maybe it will be remove by admin son :)

Comment: Thank you!  You solved my problem.  I pulled out my old laptop that I haven't used in a year that's still running 10.04, and this enabled me to update all my packages again.