# Does changing my Launchpad GPG key require any changes to my PPAs?

Tags: launchpad, gnupg

I've lost my GPG key which was used to sign my PPA. So, I generated a new key and deactivated old one in Launchpad.

Now, I would like to change the key which is used to sign repository. Currently the ppa is unavailable duo to invalid GPG signature.

My PPA: https://launchpad.net/~soroush-r/+archive/geopsy-deb

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Comment: @SirCharlo  This is not a duplicate as the OP is asking about resolving his PPA key issue, not a key issue for another PPA/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your GPG key with Launchpad is only used to sign the *PPA uploads*, NOT the generated PPA packages:

> Launchpad generates a unique key for each PPA and uses it to sign any packages built in that PPA.

Any loss/compromise of your GPG key doesn't affect the PPA signing key, and AFAIK it's not possible to change that key even if you wanted to, without creating a new LP account.

I was just able to successfully add your PPA:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.Dwh5o34jwl --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv AF89B3310ED9C8EAE449CA2694932D568ED3C834
gpg: requesting key 8ED3C834 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 8ED3C834: public key "Launchpad PPA for Soroush Rabiei" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

To resolve any local problems you're having, simply re-add the PPA signing key with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 8ED3C834
```

Comment: Last night there was `403 forbidden` errors when trying to download any package using `apt-get`. Though with browser there was no problem. I thought that it's a signature issue. Now there is no problem. Neither using apt-get nor browser. I can't see what's happening :|

Comment: Glad to know it works now - may have been a local issue with the launchpad ppa server, it gets overloaded sometimes.

Comment: Actually, packages are not signed. Repository is signed, not packages.