# Problems with signature of archive?

Tags: updates, signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

I have a Ubuntu Server VM running 12.10 and functioning as a Minecraft server.  I tried to run updates on it today and am getting an error the singature for quantal-backports doesn't match.  I get an invalid signature on that, the key is `4097EAF437D05B5` or at least that's what the error shows.

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

As my search karma or usage isn't very good and also props to the comment.

[What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Solves the entire problem, especially answer #3.