# can't update recommended Updates

Tags: update-manager

I can't update the system. The recommended Updates pops up with some updates but when I hit install it says"*Requires installation of untrusted packages*"(screen shot below ) and when I hit O.K it disappears and again the next day the Update size is larger. How do I fix this annoying issue.Anyone out there to help me?!Thanks.[image]

Comment: **sudo apt-get update -qq** worked for me and showed me what to uncheck. Have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enabled Canonical Updates from update manager settings.
2. You can use terminal and there also it will ask you the same and by giving `y` you can continue your update process.

try these two things and if issue still persists please let me know.

Comment: Hey, I've done all the above mentioned options ,still no luck.What do I do?Thanks for your time.

Comment: There you go , you got a PUBLIC key issue

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/411488/gpg-error-while-running-sudo-apt-fast-update @user279506

Answer (score 0):

Try running from terminal using sudo apt-get update -qq
the "-qq" will tell it to only display any errors it comes across. Usually this will be in the form of some packet that's not working. 
Go to 'software and sources' and disable whichever one gave the error:
[image: in this list]

Then try running sudo apt-get update again.

The NO_PUBKEY problem could be fixed by [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error) or if you prefer a GUI approach,[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) might do the trick

Comment: Mine is showing the following error:-"W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DB8ADC1CFCA9579
How do I fix this?

Comment: updated my answer to reflect the NO_PUBKEY issue. is it working?

Comment: No man, It isn't ? How do I fix this annoying issue? I've update with sudo apt-get update, still it says "W: GPG error: ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DB8ADC1CFCA9579 " I've installed Y-PPA-Manager and checked all of to fix Badsig error with no luck.Help!

Comment: I'm a little at a loss. sudo apt-get upgrade might work, then followed by sudo apt-get update, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can fix my system? I'm just numb. Little help and tip would be appreciated.