# packages cannot be authenticated! - traceroute

Tags: apt, traceroute

I am trying to install traceroute in ubuntu and I am getting the following message.

```
sudo apt-get install traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 162 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  traceroute
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? n
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

but when I install on my friend's system, it works fine.

```
sudo apt-get install traceroute
[sudo] password for ankit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 53.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 162 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe traceroute amd64 1:2.0.18-1 [53.1 kB]
Fetched 53.1 kB in 1s (28.8 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package traceroute.
(Reading database ... 207690 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking traceroute (from .../traceroute_1%3a2.0.18-1_amd64.deb) ...

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

What is wrong in my system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That message appears when your software is not up to date. So do a ...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and do the install again; the notice should be gone.

Comment: W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
got error

Comment: W: GPG error: http://oem.archive.canonical.com precise-oem-sp1 Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG F9FDA6BED73CDC22 Canonical Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@canonical.com>

    W: GPG error: http://dell.archive.canonical.com precise-dell Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG F9FDA6BED73CDC22 Canonical Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@canonical.com>

these error also

Comment: Those problems also have answers on askubuntu. Please use the search ;)

Comment: thanks. I followed second answer here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

and it worked.