# How can I update my system?

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

Currently, when I run the Update Manager in 12.04.1 LTS , I get since some weels:

[image: Screen shot]

How can I update from this state?

### Update

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
...
Hit http://at.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 198 B in 1s (146 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://at.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Also, try running `sudo apt-get update` and then run the Update manager again.

Comment: Before you start closing questions , help others then close it , as @terdon always do , let other know what is there solution maybe same question but it should be done in other solution

Comment: @nux Dupe-closing *should* help. That's the point of it. Rather than answering the exact same question infinite times, we answer it once and push everybody else there.

Comment: ok am with you , but we should ask Op about his problem , and be sure that the other answer fix his problem

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem , open terminal then try these commands :

```
sudo apt-get clean 
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old 
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again to update your system .