# The package information displayed by Ubuntu Software-Center is 17 days back and counting

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

While re-opening my Ubuntu 12.04 machine after a 2 weeks vacations, and successfully using the Update Manager to update my applications I see that

`The package information was last updated 17 days ago.`

`Press the Check button below to check for new software updates`

After an update the package information should have been updated minutes ago. How do I force the update of the package information ? I already had the problem and I know there is a file to remove or rename in the file system /var (?) something however I don't remember which one.

Thanks @ Eliah Kagan, running

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

did turn up one error related to a missing public key from an update of QGIS [qgis.org] e.g.

```
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BBA6491F47765B75
```

The solution was to run

`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BBA6491F47765B75`

Then the cmd. line returned no error and the Update Manager displayed

```
The package information was just updated.
```

The question is solved. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` tries to update this info, but Software Center should've done the equivalent. It'll likely fail... giving error messages illuminating the cause of the problem! (E.g. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723634) it was [a 404 with a PPA](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911); [there](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/203387), [a BADSIG](http://askubuntu.com/q/1877).) So please run that command, paste its output in your question, select it and Ctrl+K to format it. (Or use http://paste.ubuntu.com and edit your question with a link.)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, instead of editing th question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ Eliah Kagan, running

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

did turn up one error related to a missing public key from an update of QGIS [qgis.org] e.g.

```
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BBA6491F47765B75
```

The solution was to run

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BBA6491F47765B75
```

Then the cmd. line returned no error and the Update Manager displayed

```
The package information was just updated.
```

The question is solved. Thanks.