# Adding new PPA is causing GPG error after apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, gnupg

Recently I had a lot of GPG errors with the following message

> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY *****************

I removed them with using [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors?lq=1)

and with the help from other sites. 
But now every  time I add new PPA and try to update I got the GPG Error for the last added PPA.

Using **Y-PPA > Advanced > Try to import all missing GPG keys** removes the error/s but it will show again for every new PPA added. 
Can someone tell me why I got GPG error every time and how to fix it permanently.

using Ubuntu 14.04 x64
EDIT: 
Problem solved. I was missing /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d

Comment: how many ppas do you have? you can have only so many gpg keys installed. also, how do you add a ppa? sudo add-apt-repository?

Comment: I have around 40 PPAs , and yes I use sudo add-apt-repository. I didn't have problems  two months ago, this thing start to happen in one  month maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many ppas.

Apt can only handle 40 keys in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`.

Delete some gpg keys and ppas.

[See here for some more info.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579)

---

**EDIT**

Because you have no /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d directory, just run the following command to fix the issue:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
```

Comment: they are exactly 37 PPAs, and I did delete some before.    And I don't have /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d only - apt.conf.d, preferences.d,, sources.list.d

Comment: @Tosho sorry, the limit is 40 keys not 40 ppas. delete some keys

Comment: @Tosho also, what happened to this directory? no wonder you are having this problem adding keys, the directory does not exist.

Comment: I might deleted the folder - https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540/comments/35

Comment: just run `sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: I have /etc/apt/sources.list.d ? do you mean - /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ ?

Comment: @Tosho yes, that is it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30680/discussion-between-tosho-and-mchid).