# apt-get repository signatures were invalid

Tags: gnupg

I ran `sudo apt-get update` then got the following error:

```
GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: 
           The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 
           Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>...
```

can any one help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue by adding missing signing key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
sudo apt-get update
```

**Please note, do not add any keys from the sources You don't trust.
You are adding any keys for Your own risk.**

To fix Your issue with the `apt-get update` please do the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Comment: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>  after doing the above i got this error

Comment: Import another key using same command i gave You. Replace 16126D3A3E5C1192 with Your new badsig key, as You provided it will be 40976EAF437D05B5

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: Please paste `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in Your Original Post.

Comment: its saying no such file in the directory

Comment: Check if You typed that command correct along with the file directory.

Comment: by original post you meant what ?

Comment: Place where You asked Your main question, edit it and add there result of the `cat`

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse  this is the result

Comment: edit Your sources.list and add `http://` in front of archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Comment: I edited my answer, please check.

Comment: http:// is allready added

Comment: if its added, do the `sudo apt-get update` if that doesn't work read my edit of the answer (main post)

Comment: its not working ....

Comment: did You made `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists` and `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and after that `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: yes when i ran rm -rf / var/lib/apt/lists   it said it can not remove files failed to remove

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists`

Comment: same error every time  Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: As You provided, Your sources.list contain only one entry, right?

Comment: I dont know I am new to linux

Comment: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse` - You don't hace anything else in Your `sources.list` ?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: Generate new sources.list for Your Ubuntu: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: ok         let me do it

Comment: Is there a more powerful way of just resetting everything please? I've tried both your instructions and I still get this: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>