# I'was problem when I make " apt-get update" in my VMware

Tags: apt, error-handling

I've got a problem when I make `sudo apt-get update`. It was the error in my attached picture. I've read many solutions like my error. But I can't solve it.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

[image]

```
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

Comment: Check the following question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.