# GPG error updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

I tried the accepted solution offered in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors) but it did not solve my problem.

I did not try the solution provided Portablejim because I did not understand what the key 16126D3A3E5C1192 is for in the command:

```
sudo apt-key del 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

I also changed servers to download from but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried the suggestion from [Portablejim](https://askubuntu.com/users/33286/portablejim) in the link in my question.

I first deleted the key

```
sudo apt-key del 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

I got a response: OK

I updated repository and got no error

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And when I ran

```
sudo apt-key finger
```

I did get the "Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key"

So I went ahead with the upgrade without adding the key and it went through.