# Ubuntu Archive Bad Signature

Tags: apt, updates

I have an error when updating packages on terminal ubuntu 18.04.
When execute this command
`sudo apt-get update`

Then while update, there is an error like this

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426) bionic InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426) bionic Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                 
  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [115 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [45.5 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [36.9 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [21.5 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [189 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1176 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [75.9 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Translation-en [632 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [119 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [51.7 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [3544 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2060 B]
Fetched 1075 kB in 9s (115 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The error message is

```
The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone can fix this?

I was try using ubuntu 18.04, ubuntu mate 18.04. and both have same error like that.

Thanks before.

## How to Fix

After long time surfing at Google. I found alternate way by replacing http://archive.ubuntu.com with alternate repo from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors or we can use digitalocean mirrors repo at http://mirrors.digitalocean.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Comment: No,, I was try that. but still error. in this case, the error come from ``archive.ubuntu.com.`` and I was surf at google to search the new signature key for ``archive.ubuntu.com.`` but I can not find that.

Comment: what commands did you run listed in the duplicate ? What were the error messages.

Comment: Fixed by using mirror repo from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Suggest you post an answer to your question, then click the checkmark at left, so there's an accepted solution on record for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time surfing from google. I have alternate way to fix this problem by replacing archive.ubuntu.com repo with alternate repo from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** You're a 16-rep user already!